# Delete Table rows onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have this `function` that is called everytime an `onkeyup` activity happens in a search box. `old_tbody` is the body of a table. The id of this body is **down_body**.

```
function f1(){
    var old_tbody = document.getElementById("down_body");
    old_tbody.innerHTML = "";
    var substring = document.getElementById("search").value; //Gets the text in              the search box
    if(substring.length !== 0)
    {
        for(var obj in OBJ)
        {
            if(OBJ[obj].state=="0" && OBJ[obj].message.indexOf(substring) !== -1)
            {
                row1 = table.insertRow();
                row1.className = 'danger';

                // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
                cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
                cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);

                // Add some text to the new cells:
                cell1.innerHTML = OBJ[obj].message;
                cell2.innerHTML = OBJ[obj].status;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `function` checks a `JSON` object called **OBJ** and writes rows into the table based on the `searchbox` and other parameters.
Logically this works perfectly on the first `onkeyup` event.

But fails after the first. 2nd and 3rd events don't delete the elements like they should. It just appends entries.

Comment: So you just need a way to clear all the rows in the table before reading the `OBJ` json? How about `while(table.rows.length > 0) {  table.deleteRow(0); }`?

Comment: this is not the solution but an advice: use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`. It's better!

Comment: Thanks @ibrahimmahrir But I tried what  suggested and it worked like a charm. Seems like insertRow() doesn't exactly just replace the <tr> tag like I thought. Something in the background is going on as well.